# find $2*(4^x+2^x)=3^x-6^x+9$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I really don't know how to find x. I tried to diff but it won't works at all. Although I can find ans in wolframe but I want to know how to find it. Please help.

Comment: Please format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  It's hard to be sure exactly what your equation is.

Comment: The equation $2\times \left(4^x+2^x\right)=3^x-6^x+9$ hasn't got a very nice solution.  WA yields $x≈0.631724$.  Is that the equation you intended?

Comment: Yes, it is. Really hard.

Comment: You have to solve it by numerical methods. One thing you can try to do with differentiation is to prove that the function $2(4^x+2^x)+6^x-3^x-9$ is increasing, so that there is only one solution.

Comment: $C^x$ is a transcendental function. You will have to resort to numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, you need a numerical method and to consider that you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=2*(4^x+2^x)-(3^x-6^x+9)=2^{x+1}+2^{2 x+1}-3^x+6^x-9$$ Assuming that you prove that this is an increasing function, by inspection (or graphing), notice that $f(0)=-5$ and $f(1)=6$. So, there is a root somewhere between $0$ and $1$.

To get it, consider Newton method which, starting from a guess $x_0$, will update it according to 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ where
$$f'(x)=2^{x+1} \log (2)+2^{2 x+2} \log (2)-3^x \log (3)+6^x \log (6)$$

Let us use it using $x_0=\frac 12$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.50000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.64553363577073244675 \\
 2 & 0.63186649906103557062 \\
 3 & 0.63172424859838398232 \\
 4 & 0.63172423340791808566 \\
 5 & 0.63172423340791791247
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty signifiacnt figures.